# Exceções encadeadas em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exceção

Estou em dúvida numa situação não tão comum mas que já vi alguns desenvolvedores utilizarem que é o caso do encadeamento de exceções.

Li a documentação do Python sobre as mesmas mas não ficou tão claro como o Python atua por trás dos panos de forma a silenciar a primeira exceção.
Se puderem me dar um exemplo de código explicado seria ótimo.

Exemplo:

**Código:**

```
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Exception: ZeroDivisionError")
    raise Exception from None
```

Comment: Pode colocar na pergunta um exemplo de código que já viu que gerou essa dúvida? Da maneira que perguntou, não ficou claro.

Comment: Você diz vários except capturando diversos tipos de exceções?

Comment: Não. Digo quando você levanta uma segunda exceção no tratamento de outra.

Comment: Nunca vi alguém fazer isso (com consciência ) e não vejo motivos para fazer. Tem certeza que viu isso? Onde?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptionss

Comment: Aqui tem algumas explicações - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957829/how-to-use-raise-keyword-in-python

Comment: Eu sei como levantar uma exceção a pergunta refere-se ao encadeamento das mesmas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem muito mistério aí: o "silenciamento" de uma exceção dentro de um except faz parte da forma que Python é feito.

Sempre tem que se ter em mente que ao contrário de código compilado, onde um erro no programa  vai colocar tudo o que está em execução num estado inválido, em Python, a execução do programa está sob pelo controle do runtime do Python. Uma exceção em código Python em execução é um objeto, como outro objeto qualquer - com seus atributos  e etc... o que é diferente é que quando ocorre uma execeção (seja por que acotneceu mesmo, ou por conta de um comando `raise`), o interpretador para a execução do código Python o ponto em que está, e vai retornando de todas as funções (técnicamente, vai passando aos `frames` de execução anteriores) até achar um bloco "except" que corresponda a exceção que ocorreu (se o try/except for no mesmo ponto onde ocorreu a exceção, pode não retornar de nenhuma função). 
No ponto onde está o except, o Python associa o objeto exceção a uma variável local (a que está no `except`), e começa a executar o código do bloco `except` normalmente: nesse ponto, o prorama está consistente, e "sob controle", não numa condição de erro. Tanto que é perfeitamente válido simplesmente colocar um `pass` dentro  de uma cláusula except, para ignorar um erro (se sabemos que é um tipo de erro temporário que pode acontece de vez em quando e não atrapalha o funcionamento do programa).

Já, se existir um `raise from` dentro do  `except`, o Python simplesmente cria um novo objeto de exceção, copia alguns dados do objeto da exceção original para esse novo, e reinicia a tarefa de "ir voltando" no código até achar um except correspondente.  No caso do `raise ...from None` você esa dizendo explicitamente para não pegar dados da execeção original  -seria o mesmo que um  `raise Exception` sem o `from`.

A linguagem faz isso.  Agora por que programadores põe isso no código?  Essa talvez seja uma dúvida sua, e é uma dúvida do pessoal que se manifestou nos comentários.

Vamos pegar o exemplo  de uma aplicação web rodando dentro de um framework: as funções da aplicação web em si, como as views, são chamadas quando há uma requisição web que o framework direciona pras mesmas - mas elas não são a "porta de entrada": o framework em geral recebe dados sobre a requisção web, "disseca a url", e decide qual view é chamada, arruma um ou mais objetos internos (por exemplo "request"), e então chama a view da aplicação. Isso tudo é código Python, dentro do framework. O Framework em geral vai chamar a view para o usuário dentro de um bloco "try:/except"; Senão, qualquer exceção na view iria parar o processo de servidor do framework (ou seja, deu erro para servir uma página, o servidor todo para -não é o que vocẽ quer em geral - você quer que o servidor continue servindo outras páginas para os outros usuários e até para o que encontrou o erro).

Se esse bloco try/except do framework interceptar uam exceção da qual ele não saiba nada, ele vai gerar um erro "500" do HTTP. : Ou seja, vai olhar as configurações do seu app, ou usar as configurações padrão do prórpio framework, e retornar para o browser o html que estiver definido para qunado houver um 'erro 500". Acontece que o framework em geral vai ter exceções dele mesmo, que sua aplicação pode usar para indicar que não foi um erro "500", mas sim um erro "404" ou "403" (página não encontrada ou acesso negado), ou qualquer outro erro http (e tanto o framework quanto a sua aplicação podem quere rmostrar páginas específicas nesse caso).

Então, se dentro do código da sua view, você vai acessar o banco de dados e não encontrou o bojeto procurado - ou obteve algum outro erro, a busca pode gerar um `IndexError` (se você faz uma query ao banco, espera ter um resultado e tem zero, por exemplo) - se você deixar o IndexError "subir" até o código do framework, vai ter um erro 500. Mas no código da view, você, ao escrever o código, sabe que se acontecer um "IndexError" naquele ponto, é por que o usuário, ou outro objeto não foi encontrado no banco  - e, pode querer mostrar um "erro404" no navegador -

Então, fica um padrão natural algo do tipo

```
@view("/")
def minha_view(request):
    try:
        user = get_from_users(request.user)
    except IndexError as error:
        raise HTTPError404 from error

    # aqui continua o código para uma requisição bem sucedida
    ....
```

(No caso, o "HTTPError404" seria uma exceção definda no framework).